# CodeIgniter click any menu in mobile than login expire issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

CodeIgniter Project is working fine pc but in mobile session expire issue any page click after logout.

CodeIgniter Controller

```
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');  

    class Mechanical_rdi extends CI_Controller {  


       public function __construct()
            {
               parent::__construct();
               $this->load->model('Mechanical_model_rdi');

                if ($this->session->userdata['user'] != TRUE)
                {
                   $_SESSION['error']= 'Login first for access..';
                   echo "

                   <script>
                        window.location.href = '".base_url()."?err=1';
                   </script>

                   ";
                 }
            }
```

**config.php**

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: have you checked by turning sess_match_ip to FALSE?

Comment: ok fine sir my issue is done

Comment: please refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042209/codeigniter-is-it-still-safe-to-set-sess-match-ip-to-false) before update